# Cannot view, use, or open CDs or DVDs in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, dvd, cd

I am fairly new to Ubuntu 12.04 and I have encountered a rather irritating problem. Whenever I insert a CD or DVD (whether it have data, music, movies, or nothing at all), nothing pops up saying "you have inserted a CD", "play with Rhythmbox?" etc. It doesn't show the CD in the launcher/dock or anything of the sort.
This is especially peculiar because not only do I have a standard IDE built-in optical drive, but I have an external USB optical drive. Neither work.
In addition, whenever I go to "Computer///" and I click (double click, right click, or even left click) on "CD/DVD Drive" nothing happens, when I right click and select "Open" nothing happens either [for either of the two drives (both are listed in Computer///)]
And if I insert a blank disk and go to a disk burning program such as Brasero, and try to burn to the drive it detects no CDs or DVDs of any kind.

I'm rather stumped and can't seem to find a question similar to this. :(

Thanks for all your help in advance!! :)
~Preston

Output of sudo lshw

```
*-cdrom
               description: DVD-RAM writer
               product: CD/DVDW TS-H652M
               vendor: TSSTcorp
               physical id: 0.0.0
               bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
               logical name: /dev/cdrom
               logical name: /dev/cdrw
               logical name: /dev/dvd
               logical name: /dev/dvdrw
               logical name: /dev/sr0
               version: 0414
               capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
               configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc

*-cdrom
         description: DVD reader
         product: DVD Writer 300n
         vendor: HP
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom2
         logical name: /dev/cdrw2
         logical name: /dev/dvd2
         logical name: /dev/sr1
         version: 1.25
         serial: [
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
         configuration: status=nodisc
```

Comment: Please post output of: **sudo lshw | grep cdrom**  If nothing returned, then provide all output from: **sudo lshw**

Comment: Outcome for sudo lsh | grep cdrom

*-cdrom
                   logical name: /dev/cdrom
        *-cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrom2

Comment: So, **two** optical-media drives are being recognized.  Please paste into your question (with 4 spaces at start of each line) the output from **sudo lshw**, but just for the two sections indented after each '*-cdrom logical name' header (ie. technical details on each drive).

Comment: That looks fine.  Does it show any additional detail if you insert a disk (try internal drive first).  eg. further indented, starting with '*-medium'

Comment: It looks like the optical drives are not automounting.  To test the operation otherwise, put a disk in the IDE optical drive and type the following in a terminal window: **sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt** . The optical drive will be accessable at **/mnt**

Comment: Ok, but I did not find any section labeled *-medium  ....   And the  command sudo mount /dev/sr0/mnt did not work. Although I believed I fixed the USB optical drive, the IDE one doesn't even spin, I will open up case tomorrow and take a look at it! Thanks for everyone's help!!

Comment: you didn't resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open terminal.
2. Install the `libdvdnav4`, `libdvdread4`, `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` and `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
   ```
3. If you would like to play encrypted DVDs:

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
   ```
4. Insert a DVD into your drive. It should open automatically in the Movie Player.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/musicvideophotos/C/video-dvd.html

Comment: I had assumed issue was much earlier, that is: not loading disk.  But this can't hurt either ..

Comment: All of those packages were already installed (when ran all the commands in terminal it said I had them and they were newest version). Did what you said about encrypted DVDs, but nothing happens still :(

Comment: Sorry, ok, I think it might be a driver issue. I will try and figure this out tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I was able to get the usb optical drive working, and I am going to open my computer tomorrow to ensure my IDE optical drive is installed correctly! Thanks again!

Comment: The first package wasn't found, but this still solved the problem for me. Thanks!